# Matlab code shuffler

Tags: matlab

I am looking for a program that can take some MATLAB code as input and output a code that makes the same computation but looks as different as possible (variable renaming, math formula shuffled, looping using a different loop operator), etc. I am not looking for a code obfuscator like PCode (the output should look like it has been written by his human).

If possible:

- Free
- Can process several files at once
- Windows 7

Comment: I think you're going to have a problem with this - especially in MATLAB, I'd expect variable names to be related heavily to the underlying computation. Randomly renaming them isn't going to look human-written. Also, changing the loop operator in use is certainly possible, but it's going to look funny in a lot of cases - humans tend to think of certain problems in certain ways, and if the code has a 'while' where most people would use a 'for', it's got to attract attention.